# Correct way of starting a forever-running loop with Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've an existing code I wrote some time ago, that works but I dislike the fact that the thread I start remains in loop.

This piece of code is a consumer on an IBMMQ code, waiting for messages to be processed.The problem I've is that with the following code

```
     private Task ExecuteQueuePolling(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ConnectToAccessQueue();
                Logger.Debug($"Accessed to the queue {queueName}");

                Logger.DebugFormat("Repeating timer started, checking frequency: {checkingFrequency}",
                    checkingFrequency);

                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Logger.Trace( () => "Listening on queues for new messages");
                    //  isChecking = true;

                    var mqMsg = new MQMessage();
                    var mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions
                    { WaitInterval = (int)checkingFrequency.TotalMilliseconds };

                    // 15 second limit for waiting
                    mqGetMsgOpts.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING |
                                            MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
                    try
                    {
                        mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts);

                        if (string.Compare(mqMsg.Format, MQC.MQFMT_STRING, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                        {
                            var text = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);

                            Logger.Debug($"Message received : [{text}]");

                            Message message = new Message { Content = text };
                            foreach (var observer in observers)
                                observer.OnNext(message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Logger.Warn("Non-text message");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (MQException ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.Message == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE.ToString())
                        {
                            Logger.Trace("No messages available");
                            //nothing to do, emtpy queue
                        }
                        else if (ex.Message == MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN.ToString())
                        {
                            Logger.ErrorException("MQ Exception, trying to recconect", ex);

                            throw new ReconnectException();
                        }
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            },cancellationToken);
        }

//Calling method
  try
            {
                string queueManagerName = configuration.GetValue<string>("IBMMQ:QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME");

             //   var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName,dictionary2);

                QueueMonitor monitor = new QueueMonitor(configuration, "IMPORTER_RECEIVER_TEST");
                //_subscription = monitor.Subscribe(receiver);

                await monitor.StartAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e, "Error creating the queue monitor or it's subscription");
            }
            finally
            {

                WaitForCancel(cts);
            }
```

The call to `await monitor.StartAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);` remains pending.

How should I modify my code, so that the call returns and in background the task continue to loop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a mix of sync and async code (remember, async all the way). Also, it's unclear, what is "Calling method" and how ExecuteQueuePolling is being called.

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep`, use `await Task.Delay`

Comment: Cant read your code. also there's way to much noise in this question, you could have replicated the important bits of code in a handful of lines

Comment: Also `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>` dont return a task and make your method a void, should satisfy your needs, also use the longrunning option so you dont steal a threadpool thread

Comment: The `await` is awaiting for completion of a task so if task isn't completed it may look like pending regardless of fact that thread which initiated the task is released.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov I removed the await and it seems to work... I do some tests, thanks to all.

Comment: But by removing await you changed its semantic to fire-and-forget which doesn't allow to monitor the state of the task.

Comment: Currently the Fire-and-forget is reasonable...it's a console application that runs as a service to consume ibmmq events

Comment: One of the problems in your case that you won't be able to handle the exceptions which your code throws in certain situations.

Comment: Unfortunally this is not clear how have implemented class QueueMonitor . So why and for what you try to await StartAsync function is hard to understand too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can simplify your code by replacing `Thread.Sleep` with [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay):

```
private async Task ExecuteQueuePolling(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Process mqQueue here

        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`Task.Delay` has the advantage that accepts a `CancellationToken`, so in case of cancellation the loop will exit immediately. This could be important if the pooling of the MQ was lazier (for example every 5 seconds).

Answer (score -2):

```
    private static Task _runningTask;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _runningTask = ExecuteQueuePolling(cts.Token);
        WaitForCancel(cts);
    }

    private static void WaitForCancel(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        var spinner = new SpinWait();
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested
            && _runningTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running) spinner.SpinOnce();
    }
    private static Task ExecuteQueuePolling(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var t = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
                ; // your code
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        t.Start();
        return t;
    }
```